# Protect SQL Table to modify Data directly from Sql Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a window Application and I have some tables in database(sql server) that can be updated from the application .I need to host this database to the client machine .How I can protect our tables to be modified directly.Its a simple sql table that has some Data.Please Help.

Comment: Permissions are based on logins/users, not applications. If someone uses the same credentials to open a connection from management studio as the credentials that are used when the application opens a connection, they'll have exactly the same permissions.

Comment: But any one can access the database in "Windows Authentication" mode

Comment: Only anyone whose Windows account (or a group they belong to, directly or indirectly) has been granted (one or more) logins. And their permissions are based on the permissions granted to those logins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GRANT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms187965%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to remove the "unwanted" rights (e.g. UPDATE) from the user(s).

In general I would use [database-level roles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for that: introduce a special "read-only-role" and GRANT the needed rights (in your case only SELECT) to that role.
Second create a kind of "writer-role" and do the same (e.g. with INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE).
This is only an example - you should make clear what roles/user groups you need on database level and what rights these roles should have.

Try to keep it simple and give as few right s as possible to the users.

For further help - this [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-roles-in-sql-server-security/) gives a nice introduction.

Please also have a look at the [Identity and Access Control](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510418%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)-section of the SQL Server 2008-R2 Technet documentation.

Hope that helped a bit.
*Jost

Comment: Thanks for reply Jost.If I host database on client side then they can access it in  Windows Authentication mode and changes the role permission ? I am little weak in sql server .

Comment: At first I'm definitely not an expert of MS SQL Server. Second,  [Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb669066.aspx) in this context means (as far as I know) that the Windows users are also valid SQL Server users (without any additional authentication). so you need to set the proper rights (=grant) for these accounts or the underlying role(s).